# how to Give color of a ListBox in windows phone 8 when Backgroud is white? with a image Button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i am new to windows phone development,..
So i am preparing an application in that i given Background Color as white for every page..
in my app i added a search so that user can search data using two text Box..

In that I have given Bg color as white and foreground Color as black.. in that TextBlock is Viable But TextBox are not Visable they are mixing in background...

This is My xaml fiel..

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Margin="10,114,10,311">
        <TextBlock Text="Enter Name"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Tap="TextBlock_Tap"
                   Foreground="Black" />

        <TextBox x:Name="Enter Name Field"
                   GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" 
                   LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                   Foreground="RosyBrown" Height="46" Margin="27,0,56,0" />

        <TextBlock Text="Enter A Model number" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                   Tap="TextBlock_Tap"
                   Foreground="Black"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="Enter A Model number Field" 
                   GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" 
                   LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                   Foreground="RosyBrown" Height="46" Margin="27,0,56,0" />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Sorry i want to add a Image Button also i tried....

i want it like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="White">
  <StackPanel Margin="10,114,10,311">
   <TextBlock Text="Enter Name"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Tap="TextBlock_Tap"
                   Foreground="Black" />

    <TextBox x:Name="Enter Name Field"
                   GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2"
                   LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                   Foreground="RosyBrown" Height="46" Margin="27,0,56,0" />

     <TextBlock Text="Enter A Model number" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                   Tap="TextBlock_Tap"
                   Foreground="Black"/>

     <TextBox x:Name="Enter A Model number Field" 
                   GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" 
                   LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2"
                   Foreground="RosyBrown" Height="46" Margin="27,0,56,0" />

     <Image Height="40" Width="150" Source="your image path" Tap="Image_tap" />

     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Jaihind..  I want to view that border that's all... and i want a image Button also.. if there update it.. Thanks for answer..

Comment: @Madhu you should use Image control. Image has a tap event that work as button click event. i made an update in my ans.

Answer (score 1):

add `Background="Black"` (or whatever color you want) in all your `TextBox`.
For that what you have shown use `BorderBrush="Black"`, decrease the border thickness if you need to. Yes, you can add a image button, use a image as your button background.

```
<Button>
     <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush Source="your_file.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
     </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

---

Note: It is not a good idea to write `x:Name` value with spaces. what you write in `x:Name` ultimately become a variable name of type `TextBox` (in this case) and c# doesn't permit variable name with space, So just delete the spaces and use `x:Name="Enter_A_Model number_Field"` or simply `x:Name="EnterAModelNumberField"`

Comment: Thanks Deeiip But they are very bright can i dicrease there pixcel.. And can i add a image Button for search.. This is the final one ... thanks for answer.. Please update your answer..

Comment: hi..Dipanjan Nag ..So what should i do at. x:name

Answer (score 1):

Use your textbox surrounded with border, since you are using a white background.I think below code may help you to get an idea.

```
<Border  BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="brdUsrName"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Background="Black">
<TextBox Name="txtUserName"  Margin="-10,-10,-10,-10"  />
</Border>
```